# How can I mix two PCM audio files

Tags: java, android, audio, pcm

I did test mix two PCM audio file.
but don't get true audio file.

I used this [example](http://mobilengineering.blogspot.com/2012/06/audio-mix-and-record-in-android.html) 
  So, my code:

```
  private void mixSound() throws IOException {

byte[] music1 = null;
music1 = new byte[in1.available()];
music1 = convertStreamToByteArray(in1);
in1.close();


byte[] music2 = null;
music2 = new byte[in2.available()];
music2 = convertStreamToByteArray(in2);
in2.close();

byte[] output = new byte[music1.length];

for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {

samplef1 = music1[i] / 128.0f; 
samplef2 = music2[i] / 128.0f;

float mixed = samplef1 + samplef2;
// reduce the volume a bit:
mixed *= 0.8;
// hard clipping
if (mixed > 1.0f) mixed = 1.0f;

if (mixed < -1.0f) mixed = -1.0f;

byte outputSample = (byte) (mixed * 128.0f);
output[i] = outputSample;

} //for loop

save = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
save.write(output);
save.flush();
save.close();
}

public byte[] convertStreamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buff = new byte[8000];
int i;
while ((i = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > 0) {
baos.write(buff, 0, i);
}

return baos.toByteArray(); // be sure to close InputStream in calling function

}
```

2 audio files with bit rate 64000 & sampling rate 16000 GH & sterio

```
in1 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.a_2);
in2 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.a_diz_2);
```

Also try to convert
 `bytes array to short array -> then calculate-> then convert short to byte` using converts methods 
like bytes2Shorts(byte[] buf) and shorts2Bytes(short[] s). 
But steel have a fail result.

Someone can say me Where is my wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues here and I'll try to address some of them

First, using `byte[]` suggests that your `PCM wave data format` is `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT` (or it should be this format if it already isn't). This format uses `8-bit (1 byte) unsigned`, which means that the sound
samples are stored in the `[0, 255]` range (not in the `[-127, +128] or [-128,+127]` range).

This means that the negative values are in the `[0, 127]` range and the positive samples are in the `[128,255]` range.

When mixing values, it's best to prevent `clipping` right from the start so I'd use

```
byte mixed = (music1[i] + music2[i])/2; //this ensures that mixed remains within the `correct range` for your PCM format
```

You can also divide your samples by 128 (if you want to convert them to floating point values)

```
float samplef1 = (((float)music1[i]-127)/128 ; //converting samples to [-1, +1] range -- -1 corresponds a sample value of 0 and +1 to 255

float samplef2 = (((float)music2[i]-127)/128;

float mixed = (samplef1+samplef2)/2;
```

Note that you now have 2 options to play data(samples) generated in this way. Either, convert `floats` back to `bytes` or use the `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT` format.

> audio files with bit rate 64000 & sampling rate 16000 GH & sterio

This can't be correct. Typical sampling rates are `4000Hz, 8000Hz, 11000Hz, 16000Hz, 22050Hz or 44100Hz`. For bit depths, audio usually uses `8 bits, 16 bits or 32 bits`.

For instance, CD quality audio uses `44100Hz, 16bit, stereo` format.

Comment: Hi! I agree and thought now the same. I will try, thanks a at all